# How to install a setup project for every user on the system?

Tags: c#, outlook, registry, installation, add-in

I have created a Set up project which is used to install add-ins in the Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 using VS 2010, after installation the add-in is working good on my user account, but the setup is still not installed on the other user accounts.

So, my question is how to configure or change the setup project properties to make the add-in installed for every user on a system. As I have saved the registry key in

HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddin

I kept it in Local Machine to make it readable and static for every user.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: If you install it as a admin it should shown to all users....

Comment: Actually I have done this only but its not working. Rest I'll retry it on diff system

Comment: Check your privileges